# cahnging the default 'Edit List' SPD option

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-designer

We are running SharePoint 2010 and I recently installed SharePoint Designer 2013 and now whenever I go to any lists in SharePoint 2010 under list settings and select 'Edit List' button for SPD it tries and load SPD 2013 and throws an error that it can't load 2010 sites in 2013 designer how do I change the 'edit list' default to go back to SPD2010

Answer (score 0):

Use SPD 2010 instead of SPD 2013 , Alot of changes have been made to SPD2013

Comment: I have them both installed, to use 2013 on a test site, but the majority of the applications use 2010, but on any list's tool bar the SPD 'edit list' button defaults to 2013 :( and not the 2010, how can I change the 'edit list' button to point to SPD 2010 and not 2013 without uninstalling 2013 and reinstalling 2010